# Problem with scraping data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I have written the following trial code to retreive the title of legislative acts from the European parliament.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

search_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A7-2010-%.4d&language=EN"

for number in xrange(1,10):   
    url = search_url % number
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    title = soup.findAll("title")
    print title
```

However, whenever I run it i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have narrowed it down to BeautifulSoup not being able to read the fourth document in the loop. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

With kind regards

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
print title
```

with

```
for t in title:
    print(t)
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(t.string for t in title))
```

works. I'm not entirely sure why `print <somelist>` sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't however.

Answer (score 4):

BeautifulSoup works in Unicode, so it's not responsible for that *decoding* error.  More likely, your problem comes with the `print` statement -- your standard output seems to be in ascii (i.e., `sys.stdout.encoding = 'ascii'` or absent) and therefore you would indeed get such errors if trying to print a string containing non-ascii characters.

What's your OS?  How is your console AKA terminal set (e.g. if on Windows what "codepage")?  Did you set in the environment `PYTHONIOENCODING` to control `sys.stdout.encoding` or are you just hoping the encoding will be picked up automatically?

On my Mac, where the encoding **is** correct detected, running your code (save for also printing the number together with each title, for clarity) works fine and shows:

```
$ python ebs.py 
1 [<title>REPORT Report on the proposal for a Council regulation temporarily suspending autonomous Common Customs Tariff duties on imports of certain industrial products into the autonomous regions of Madeira and the Azores - A7-0001/2010</title>]
2 [<title>REPORT Report on the proposal for a Council directive concerning mutual assistance for the recovery of claims relating to taxes, duties and other measures - A7-0002/2010</title>]
3 [<title>REPORT Report on the proposal for a regulation of the European Parliament and of the Council amending Council Regulation (EC) No 1085/2006 of 17 July 2006 establishing an Instrument for Pre-Accession Assistance (IPA) - A7-0003/2010</title>]
4 [<title>REPORT on equality between women and men in the European Union – 2009 - A7-0004/2010</title>]
5 [<title>REPORT Report on the proposal for a Council decision on the conclusion by the European Community of the Convention on the International Recovery of Child Support and Other Forms of Family Maintenance - A7-0005/2010</title>]
6 [<title>REPORT on the proposal for a Council directive on administrative cooperation in the field of taxation - A7-0006/2010</title>]
7 [<title>REPORT Report on promoting good governance in tax matters - A7-0007/2010</title>]
8 [<title>REPORT Report on the proposal for a Council Directive amending Directive 2006/112/EC as regards an optional and temporary application of the reverse charge mechanism in relation to supplies of certain goods and services susceptible to fraud - A7-0008/2010</title>]
9 [<title>REPORT Recommendation on the proposal for a Council decision concerning the conclusion, on behalf of the European Community, of the Additional Protocol to the Cooperation Agreement for the Protection of the Coasts and Waters of the North-East Atlantic against Pollution - A7-0009/2010</title>]
$
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I do indeed use a Mac, how have you setup yours? Right now I am just hoping the encoding will be picked up automatically (I am still learning about this whole confusing encoding business:))

Comment: @Thomas, I haven't done any setup -- works out of the box (utf8 is the default for Terminal.App, I believe -- if not, then that's the only thing I have set in Terminal's preferences).  What's `sys.stdout.encoding` in your Python (indeed, what's your Python and MacOSX?  I have OSX 10.5 and it works with Apple-distributed Python 2.5, and python.org-distributed 2.4, 2.6 and 3.1 -- all out of the box and no environment variable setting).

Comment: Hi alex, I am using MacOSx 10.5.8 and python 2.6.

Comment: And what does sys.stdout.encoding show in a Py2.6 session?  (I don't see how the editor changes things -- or are you running your python code from _inside_ your editor, perchance, rather than on a normal Terminal.App?).

Comment: If i run sys.std.encoding i get "us-ascii". Thanks for spending your time with helping me Alex!

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce the problem Thomas describes under Ubuntu 9.10, python 2.6.4, and with `sys.stdout.encoding` UTF-8.

Comment: @Thomas, `us-ascii` (presumably in `sys.stdout.encoding` -- not `sys.std.encoding` as you write) would surely cause horrible problems -- how's the Terminal.App set (assuming that's the output destination)?  If utf8 as it should be, not sure why it's not being picked p -- have you tried setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` in the environment?

Comment: @~unutbu, what terminal emulator, and how set?  And is PYTHONIOENCODING set, and, if so, how?

Comment: @Alex: I get the UnicodeEncodeError with `PYTHONIOENCODING` set to `UTF-8` and also if unset (the default). My terminal emulator is GNOME Terminal 2.28.1 (the default with Ubuntu 9.10). The terminal menu item Terminal>"Set Character Encoding" is set to "Unicode (UTF-8)". Here is the terminal log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/458752/ .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the titles to a file, you need to specify some encoding that can represent the non-ascii char, utf8 should work fine. To do this, you need to add:

```
out = codecs.open('titles.txt', 'w', 'utf8')
```

at the top of the script

and print to the file:

```
print >> out, title
```

Comment: Hi Maltjuv, thanks for the help, but it still gives me the same error.